# Uncaught exception "MongoCursorException" for PHP and MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

**Error message**

There is a problem with my PHP code and I keep getting this error message (see below) on my webpage. What does it mean and how can I solve it?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'localhost:27017: Can't canonicalize query: TypeMismatch: "$search" had the wrong type. Expected String, found NULL'
```

**PHP**

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
//Connect to MongoDB
$mongoClient = new MongoClient();

//Select a database
$db = $mongoClient->ecommerce;

//Extract the data that was sent to the server
$search_string = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//Create a PHP array with our search criteria
$findCriteria = [
    '$text' => ['$search' => $search_string] 
];

//Find all of the customers that match  this criteria
$cursor = $db->products->find($findCriteria);

//Output the results
echo "<h1>Results</h1>";
foreach ($cursor as $cust) {
    echo "<p>";
    echo "product name: " . $cust['name'];
    echo "</p>";
}

//Close the connection
$mongoClient->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because $search_string is null instead of being string as the error message says.

Check if `$_POST['name']` is not empty before doing operations. To solve it make POST request to this file from your form or change the type according to your needs.

Comment: Which part of my code in the PHP do I need to change or add?